# Getting parameters from query string in Zend Framework 2.3

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a RESTful API which should handle queries like:
/api/elements/search/?filter={json_here}.

Please tell me how can I catch get-parameter $_GET['filter'] from query string in latest ZF2 (v2.3.3) and get my json filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller you can access it using `$this->params()->fromQuery('filter')`